# create a list of dictionaries boto AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I am trying to create a list of all alarm attributes and their value. This is what I am trying to do.

```
import json
import boto.ec2.cloudwatch

conn = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-1')
alarms = conn.describe_alarms()

single_dict = {}

whitelist = ["name", "metric", "namespace", "statistic", "comparison", "threshold",    "period", "evaluation_periods", "unit", "description", "dimensions", "alarm_actions", "insufficient_data_actions", "ok_actions"]
x = []
for alarm in alarms:
    for attr in whitelist:
        single_dict[attr] = getattr(alarm, attr)

    print single_dict
    x.append(single_dict)
print x
```

This solution is not working. I get a list with dictionaries that contains the same values always. But i try to print single_dict like in example, get the right values for each iteration. Cant understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filling `x` with references to **the same dictionary object**. Dictionaries in Python are mutable, they can be changed in-place, so although you alter the dictionary on each iteration (and thus see the appropriate result printed) this also alters all of the "other dictionaries" in the list.

Try this:

```
whitelist = ["name", "metric", "namespace", "statistic", "comparison", "threshold",    "period", "evaluation_periods", "unit", "description", "dimensions", "alarm_actions", "insufficient_data_actions", "ok_actions"]
x = []
for alarm in alarms:
    single_dict = {} # new dictionary object each time
    for attr in whitelist:
        single_dict[attr] = getattr(alarm, attr)

    print single_dict
    x.append(single_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same dict object each time, so x is just a bunch of references to that same one. How about:

```
x = [{attr: getattr(alarm, attr)} for alarm in alarms for attr in whitelist]
```